# Finding and deleting files with users machine name at the end

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

Hi SharePoint stackers,

I am very new to sharepoint and powershell but I have an issue where a user's machine that has not been online for sometime that has then uploaded a huge amount of files and created copies with their user machine name at the end e.g filename-users machine.docx

I need to search through the whole team site and find the files in error that are there and remove all copies of these files. Doing this manually by searching is not an option so ideally need a powershell script that can help find and remove these files.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Are the files you are trying to track down spread across many site collections?  (BTW - Often a site collection = a department)

Comment: its just one site collection but a few libraries within that one collection.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear properly, what's the role of user machine in sharepoint farm or web application.
 if he is uploading some files and internet disconnected so some files uploaded successfully or some is not, is this the scenario or what?